# Most Efficient way of freqently(every 5 secs) updating/maintaining a file/vector mirror?

Tags: c++, file, stl

**1)** I have a file whose contents are mirrored via a vector type container.

**2)** The file contents are checked( for changes ) every 5 secs or so.

**3)** Any changes made to the file causes the vector to be updated, thus the mirror is maintained.

**4)** The contents of the vector are displayed on a screen in real time.

This problem must come up a lot, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer.  It could be the answer just happens to be unsatisfactory, the two are not mutually exclusive, but lets see...

### Possible Solutions:

Using basic C++ and the STL only.

**1) File Data Length or Last Read Position.**

After each read, store last read position.
Any new reads start from last read position.

Cons:

Any changes to existing file data will remain undetected.

**2) Hash Check.**

After each read, store the hash of each file line, which can be used later to check/read new file data.

Pro:

Any changes to file contents are reflected in the vector.

Con:

Every file line has be read, hashed and stored....twice!

Overhead as file grows in size.

**3) No Checks.**

Don't check anything just read the entire file and overwrite the vector each time, regardless of changes to the file contents.

Pro:

Any changes to the file contents will be reflected in the vector.

Con:

?

Comment: "Entire file data still needs to be read to determine current file data length" nope, just seek to the last read position and start reading from there to append to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows, just let the OS notify you on changes in the monitored folder.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

this way you do not need to poll and also get info about changes to file attributes (e.g. last write)

once you know a actual change happended, you can read/update.

not sure how its done for other operating systems.

Comment: Once notified of a change to the file, ...would you then read the entire file and overwrite the existing vector?

Comment: depends on the kind of modifications to the file you expect. If there is only data appended, you can skip the first part and extend. if there are other modifications, reading the whole file might be the least error-prone approach.

Comment: @LearnMore What platform _are_ you on?  Different OS's provide different notification mechanisms.